# How to create a CPU Queue Length graph Kibana?

Tags: kibana, metricbeat

I'm looking at making a Processor / CPU Queue Length graph on Kibana from some metricbeats stats that I have, and I was wondering how to do it / if it is possible. From having a search around I cannot seem to find a lot about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using topbeat for ELK it will helpful to get the system infrastructure metrics.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/topbeat/current/_step_5_loading_sample_kibana_dashboards.html

Comment: Wasn't metricbeat just the replacement for topbeat (Which I'm using now) - it just feels like it would be a step backwards. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can use metricbeat. But I have't enough idea to answer the problem.     https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-sample-dashboards.html